# Is there an application which organizes my "Downloads" folder automatically?

Tags: software-recommendation, automation

I'm looking for an application which

- puts all files from my Downloads folder into a new generated folder (called like the date) per button press or automatically
- is able to move files to its destinated directory automatically (p.e. *.png files should be put into `/home/user/pictures/random/`, *.avi to `/videos/`, ...)

If you are familiar with the [DayFolder application](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/dayfolder-automatically-organizes-your-cluttered-ubuntu-desktop): I'm looking for an application like that but for any folder (not only the Desktop). In my case that's Downloads because this folder gets cluttered on my PC very fast.

Thanks for your advice/help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question and the author has probably already found a solution, however, for the benefit of others that might have the same problem, DayFolder now does everything described above. I just installed it and its working beautifully. You can find information on how to add the ppa on the author's launchpad page here https://launchpad.net/~thejambi/+archive/thejambi

Comment: I just installed DayFolder and thanks to you, I finally have the application I was looking for. Little sluggish design, but otherwise all the options I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Save the following script in a text file. Call it "susan.sh" (or something else).

```
#!/bin/bash

# define target directories
VIDEOS=/videos/
PICTURES=$HOME/pictures/random

# this will generate directories in form /home/user/Downloads-2012-09-05
REMAINDER=$HOME/Downloads-`date +%Y-%m-%d`
DOWNLOADS=$HOME/Downloads/

cd $HOME

# adapt to suit your needs
mv $DOWNLOADS/*.{jpg,png,JPEG,jpeg,PNG,tif,tiff,TIF,TIFF,gif,GIF} $PICTURES
mv $DOWNLOADS/*.{mov,avi} $VIDEOS
if [ ! -d "$REMAINDER" ] ; then mkdir "$REMAINDER" ; fi
mv $DOWNLOADS/* "$REMAINDER"
```

Make susan.sh executable and put it somewhere safe:

```
chmod a+x susan.sh
sudo cp susan.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Run it a few times from terminal to make sure it runs correctly. If you are happy with the results, create a desktop launcher. Save the following in a text file called susan.desktop in your Desktop folder:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Susan
GenericName=Downloads directory sorter
Comment=automagically sort the contents of the Downloads directory
Exec=/usr/local/bin/susan.sh
```

Do people really create "applications" to do such simple tasks?

Comment: I'm (a bit) familiar with bash scripting so I figured that I could create/look for a script for that. But I'm looking for an application to do that simple task because I find bash scripts uneasy to manage (configuration via text editor, bugs have to be fixed by yourself, etc.) and I'm no Linux power user who wants to program everything himself. I like Linux a lot for the freedom it gives me but I'm more the lazy user type - like the majority of PC (mainly Windows) users. BUT you script looks rock solid and does everything I asked for so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ha consider yourself lucky! Someone just recently made an application for the ubuntu appshowdown called "circle" which does just what you want :)

EDIT: Here is a relevant youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvTl3-bo-xI

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Circle does not do entirely what I have in mind. The program should sort all the pictures into my Pictures folder etc. DayFolder can do that with the Desktop so I hope there is a program out there which can do this for any folder. But Circle is a step in the right direction definitely. =)